# How to exclude records from SQL query?

Tags: sql, select, oracle19c, exclude-constraint

Given the following SQL query:

```
select t 
from tableA t, tableA t2 
where t.validAt = :validAt1 and t2.validAt = :validAt2 
and t.uniqueId = t2.uniqueId 
and nvl(t.code, 'xNVLx') != nvl(t2.code, 'xNVLx');
```

the result is that I get the records of the records with a changed value of column CODE.
So far so good.

**Examples**:

**CHANGES**:

```
CODE changed from  123  -> 456:  IS IN RESULT SET, PERFECT
CODE changed from  123  -> NULL: IS IN RESULT SET, PERFECT
CODE changed from  NULL -> 123:  IS IN RESULT SET, PERFECT
```

**NO CHANGES:**

```
CODE changed from  NULL -> NULL: NOT IN RESULT SET, PERFECT
CODE changed from  123  -> 123:  NOT IN RESULT SET, PERFECT
```

Now there are two additional special cases that are to be added:

**SPECIAL CASES:**

```
Special Case 1: CODE changed from  NULL -> 00: SHALL NOT BE RESULT SET
Special Case 2: CODE changed from  NULL -> 01: SHALL NOT BE RESULT SET
```

**Question**: is there an elegant an simple SQL exclude existing?

EDIT:

I used the solution like proposed from @Plirkee:

```
and nvl(        decode(t.code,
                  '00','xNVLx',
                  '01','xNVLx',
                  t.code),
                'xNVLx')
                != nvl(
                decode(t2.code,
                  '00','xNVLx',
                  '01','xNVLx',
                  t2.code),
                'xNVLx')
```

**but**: with this logic change from "00" to "01" is treated as valid which should not.

Any ideas?

Comment: `WHERE NOT` ?  Or, `<>` ?  It depends.  And it's not clear exactly what you're attempting to exclude.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: you are using  decode on both sides...this not what I proposed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `decode` function

```
select t 
from tableA t, tableA t2 
where t.validAt = :validAt1 and t2.validAt = :validAt2 
and t.uniqueId = t2.uniqueId 
and nvl(t.code, 'xNVLx') != nvl(decode(t2.code,'00','xNVLx','01','xNVLx',t2.code), 'xNVLx');
```

Comment: did you see my EDIT?

Comment: @DerBenniAusA saw it just now..what do you mean by 'valid'? In proposed solution 00 is converted to 'xNVLx' , 01 is also converted. to 'xNVLx' rest values remain the same...

Comment: @DerBenniAusA  this is done on the right. side only.

Comment: I solved it this way now:  and not (
                  nvl(t.code, 'xNVLx')
                    = nvl(t2.code, 'xNVLx')
                  or t.code is null and t2.code = '00'
                  or t.code is null and t2.code = '01'
                )

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your logic as:

```
select . . .
from tableA t join
     tableA t2 
     on t.validAt = :validAt1 and t2.validAt = :validAt2 and
        t.uniqueId = t2.uniqueId 
where t.code <> t2.code or (t.code is not null and t.code is null);
```

Comment: @DerBenniAusA . .  I can't parse your comment in a reasonable way.  This answers the question.